# CSS Screen & Print Issue

Tags: html, css

I need to display the following div’s as it is on the screen according to the HTML, but when I print the Claimant Name, Case Info, Contacts, Files should print on 1st page and Claimant Name, Service should print on 2nd page.

Can someone please show me a way to solve it using CSS?

```
<body>        
    <div>Claimant Name</div>

    <div>Case Info</div>    

    <div>Contacts</div>

    <div>Files</div>

    <div>Service</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not possible without some complex jQuery magic or duplicating elements in conjunction with a print stylesheet. Have you considered offering a custom print view?

Comment: @Pekka, if the markup cannot change then you are correct.  Scripting would be necessary to add the name again.  I suppose a jQuery $('body > div:first-child') would target the first div in the body allowing you to duplicate it to the correct position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same answer I posted at CSS Creator:

DIV doesn't lend any semantic meaning so there's most definitely a better way to mark it up.  It does involve adding a second name field but I don't see that as any sort of problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Le documents judiciaires</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #secondPage .name {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <style title="text/css" media="print">
        #secondPage {
            page-break-before: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="firstPage">
        <div class="name">Claimant Name</div>
        <div>Case Info</div>
        <div>Contacts</div>
        <div>Files</div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondPage">
        <div class="name">Claimant Name</div>
        <div>Service</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot guarantee how HTML is printed** - it simply isn't possible.  If you need to guarantee how a document will print you'll need to create something like a PDF using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/) or similar

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to show and hide various elements on a monitor display and a printed version.  for instance, you could have Claimant Name on the document twice, but the second one is hidden on the screen.  It could be visible when printed.

**However**, you can't control paging when a web page is printed.  You may want to consider a pdf or other printed document format for that.  HTML is much more oriented towards browser display than paper printout.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see this when I posted my answer as I was looking for the code I posted on the other forum.  It's basically the same thing I said except with page-break-after/page-break-before you can control paging.  I'm sure that's browser dependent though.  I wouldn't put it past IE to mess that up somehow.  :)

Comment: No worries, you explained a *lot* more thoroughly.  Plus, I might be wrong. +1 to you :)

Comment: I agree that creating a PDF would be ideal to control printed page layout but if it's just a few lines of text thrown out on a page, like the mess that court papers usually are, then html will probably do well enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

With [the page break properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-break-props) (browser support is variable). Make sure that your stylesheet applies to print media.